# Unknown syntax error on creating a simple widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, syntax-error

I was following this tutorial (http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/#add_button) on making widgets with Tkinter. I have been making sure to follow it very carefully but, when I run it now in step 10, I get an  "Invalid Syntax" Error. Here the code:

```
import tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')

        button = tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click me !")
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

The IDLE points the error is in this line, selecting the second quotation marks:

```
button = tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click me !**"**)
```

The tutorial was written in Python 2, but I'm using Python 3. Can anyone see what is the error and what to do to fix it (in Python 3)?

Thanks in advance for any help, I am new to programming and English is not my native language.

Comment: Why are you using the `u"string"` in Python 3?  All strings are always Unicode in Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `u"Click me !**"` with `"Click me !**"`

The `u` indicates a Unicode string (type `unicode` instead of `str`) in Python 2, but in Python 3, the distinction between the `str` and `unicode` types is gone and the `u` is scrapped.

Comment: This is not entirely true. `str` objects from Python 2 behave close to `bytes` in Python 3.

Comment: @patrys: yes, so there's now a distinction between `bytes` and `str`, but still the distinction between `str` and `unicode` is no more; from the viewpoint of text handling, that's the major change.

Comment: What I meant is that the current situation is better described as “`str` got renamed to `bytes` with the `b` prefix and `unicode` got renamed to `str` losing its `u` prefix”.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `u` prefix for unicode strings in Python 3.